# Observation regarding father's name change in passport affecting visa application?

Tags: visas, schengen, paperwork

While renewing my passport in 2010, as my father had changed the way he spelled his name, with due legal process, my new passport has the changed spelling but with an observation to that effect written down.

While applying for a Schengen visa for a holiday to Switzerland, the VFS (Visa  Facilitation Services) person told me that there is a good chance my visa will be denied for this reason. All my other papers are in order. Is this likely to happen?

Comment: The idea that your passport's observation documenting your father's legal name change would result in a visa refusal is baffling.  The problem, though, is that Schengen refusals are not very informative, so if the visa *is* refused, you will probably not have a good way of knowing definitively whether the observation or the name change had anything to do with the refusal.

Comment: The VFS people are very frequently mistaken, and sometimes their mistakes cause people to get refused. If they tell you something, you should confirm it before you believe it as true.

Answer (score 4):

Regardless of what may have been said by an individual at VFS Global, it is an application centre and not in a position to judge the quality of what is presented, only what is included and whether it is complete. Its sole function is to manage *visa and passport issuance-related administrative and non-discretionary tasks for its client governments.*

The discretionary task, examination of application and supporting documents, is done by the goverment officials who make the decision on granting a visa.

Reference: [Wikipedia VFS Global overview](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/VFS_Global)